# MySQL concat column in date_format

Tags: mysql, date

I have this table: table1, and four varaible `$START_MONTH` `$START_YEAR` `$END_MONTH` `$END_YEAR` which return: *month:1, year: 2014* and *3, 2015*

```
+----+-----+-------+------+-------------+
| ID | DAY | MONTH | YEAR | DESCRIPTION |
+----+-----+-------+------+-------------+
| 1  | 1   |   1   | 2014 | Product 1   |
| 2  | 1   |   2   | 2015 | Product 2   |
| 3  | 2   |   3   | 2014 | Product 1   |
| 4  | 10  |   1   | 2015 | Product 3   |
| 5  | 9   |   5   | 2015 | Product 3   |
+----+-----+-------+------+-------------+

SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT (CONCAT (DAY,' ', MONTH,' ',YAR), GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) AS NEW_DATA,
  DESCRIPTION

FROM table1

WHERE
NEW_DATA BETWEEN $START_MONTH . $START_YEAR AND $END_MONTH . $END_YEAR
```

I need return the rows included between: *1.2014* and *3.2015*. Thank you!

Comment: Store dates as a single entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you can filter by combined columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (`YEAR`, `MONTH`) >= (2014,1)
  AND (`YEAR`, `MONTH`) <= (2015,3)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87000/2

**Update:** As Strawberry stated, MySQL will not use an index for this condition. But it's not that it's impossible - MySQL is just missing this optimisation. As far as i know PostgreSQL is fine with this kind of index range check. So we can hope that MySQL/MariaDB will support it in the future.

However, if you face performance problems, you can add redundant conditions for the year range:

```
WHERE (`YEAR`, `MONTH`) >= (2014,1)
  AND (`YEAR`, `MONTH`) <= (2015,3)
  AND `YEAR` >= 2014
  AND `YEAR` <= 2015
```

This way MySQL will first filter the rows by `YEAR` using an index like `YEAR, MONTH` or `YEAR, MONTH, DAY` (or any index that starts with `YEAR`).

All alternatives i know are not very readable and no of them can use an index:

```
WHERE DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', `YEAR`, `MONTH`, 1)) >= '2014-01-01'
  AND DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', `YEAR`, `MONTH`, 1)) <= '2015-03-01'
```

Or

```
WHERE (`YEAR` = 2014 AND `MONTH` >= 1)
   OR (`YEAR` = 2015 AND `MONTH` >= 3)
   OR (`YEAR` > 2014 AND `YEAR` < 2015)
```

If you are fighting for every milisecond you can also create an [indexed generated (virtual) column (MySQL 5.7)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
`DATE` AS STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`),'%Y-%m-%d') VIRTUAL KEY
```

And query like:

```
WHERE `DATE` >= '2014-01-01'
  AND `DATE`  < '2015-04-01'
```

Comment: Not work, my error is: #1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Comment: @ster - It seams not to work with BETWEEN. Try the new version.

Comment: Note that this kind of query cannot use an index.

Comment: @Strawberry - I must agree and disagree: The query can use an index but MySQL does not.

Comment: In the context of a question about MySQL, that's kind of the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that it's not a logical limitation but a question of implementation. However thanks for your comment - I forgot about the index issue, even though i already faced this problem with separate date and time columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT (CONCAT (DAY,' ', MONTH,' ',YEAR), GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) AS NEW_DATA,
  DESCRIPTION
FROM table1
WHERE
(YEAR BETWEEN $START_YEAR AND $END_YEAR) 
AND (MONTH BETWEEN $START_MONTH AND $END_MONTH)
```

Comment: Not work, return only months (1,2 and 3) of the years (2014,2015)